# What is the difference between WCF's ClientOperations' ParameterInspectors and ClientParameterInspectors?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

If you open the documentation for the [ClientOperation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.clientoperation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you'll see that there are two collections that seemingly serve the same purpose: adding parameter inspectors.

They are:

> [public ICollection<IParameterInspector> ClientParameterInspectors { get; }](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.clientoperation.clientparameterinspectors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
>   [public SynchronizedCollection<IParameterInspector> ParameterInspectors { get; }](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.clientoperation.parameterinspectors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There is a remark on the documentation for the first one that states that "ClientParameterInspectors is a thread-safe collection."

It seems that ClientParameterInspectors was introduced in 4.5, does anyone know the reason for this?